# jQuery tab pane

Tags: javascript, jquery

I referred [this](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#manipulation)  and downoaded `jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom` library (all 31 components as mentioned in [here](http://jqueryui.com/download))

I followed the sample code. But it didn't work. Here is my full code.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery UI Tabs - Default functionality</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="1_6js.js"></script>// this is 1.6 jQuery pluging and it works well in other pages    
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.min.js"></script>  // this is my jquery ui plugin

    <script>
    $(function() {

                alert("hi")  // this alert showed in browser

        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
                alert("oh") // this alert is also showed.
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="demo">

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">tab 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">tab 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">tab 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        Content 1
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        Content 2
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        Content 3

    </div>
</div>

</div><!-- End demo -->

</body>
</html>
```

I don't need any css styles. I need only a working simple tab pane and I can improve later.  I put `$( "#tabs" ).tabs();`  in the body tag inside a </script> tag. it also didn't work. Any one can let me know where I have missed or where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add related css like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.css" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: Thanks Ghokun. Then only a css added. but not functioning.

Comment: but with a different css solved the problem. http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css . Thanks

Comment: Oh that was just random CSS href in my post!

Comment: @AashMaharoon I think you should maybe delete your answer and select Ghokus answer as the correct one.  Of course you have to link it correctly or else it does nothing, the point of his answer was to include the css file for jquery ui, not to show where to link it from.

Answer (score 0):

adding `http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css` solved the problem.